# Disambiguate HTML form `action` property from input element with `name="action"`

Tags: javascript

```
<form action="theurl"><input name="somethingelse"></form>
<form action="theurl"><input name="action"></form>

// document.forms[0].action == 'theurl'

// document.forms[1].action == '[object HTMLInputElement]'
// document.forms[1].getAttribute('action') == 'theurl'
```

The first form works as expected.

For the second form, is there a way for `document.forms[1].action` to refer to the form's `action` property instead of the input element with `name="action"`? Obviously `getAttribute()` will work, but for learning purposes, is there another way to do this?

Comment: you could add `form=""` to the input element, but then it will not get submitted with the form. Alternatively you could not set an action on the form and use a `type="submit"` input with a `formaction` attribute.